# string to php timestamp

Tags: php, date, timestamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [convert any date string to timestamp without timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300141/convert-any-date-string-to-timestamp-without-timezone)

I have a string that looks like this and want a php timestamp format.
I can ask client to change format of the string if necessary.

2010/08/11 06:33:00

Answer (score 0):

Use strtotime:

```
$date = date('Y/m/d H:i:s', strtotime('2010/08/11 06:33:00'));
```